# Dismiss The Alarm from HomeScreen , any quick way?

Tags: android

Developing an Alarm app, The app is able to set alarm, and it plays the default sound in the set time. However, in the default Android Alarmclock , when an alarm rings, it opens a dialog to dismiss the alarm, My question is Do I need to create that sort of custom Activity from my app, to be able to dismiss the alarm, or are there any default options in Android to invoke them.

Here is the code to the Service that I use in my app :

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {
private NotificationManager alarmNotificationManager;

public AlarmService() {
super("AlarmService");
}

@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
sendNotification("Wake Up! Wake Up!");
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
Log.d("AlarmService", "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, Time_Date.class), 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(

this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);


alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification sent.");
}
}
```

Comment: just call an activity in onRecieve when u want to dismiss the alarm

Comment: Can you explain it a bit further?

Comment: what u want actually ? to dismiss the alarm in a separate activity ?

Comment: You will have to create your own dismiss dialog

Comment: i think he wants to create an activity to stop ...#jibran

Comment: It is not a concern if its from a different Activity, I need a pop up dialog to dismiss the alarm, Should I use a separate Dialog for that ? Or just like Android's built in TimePicker and DatePicker , are there any options for that from AlarmManager ?